# When I try to launch url then it not run but on bowser it run well

Tags: flutter

```
component name for http://164.52.195.127:8080/ProductCatalogManagement/mFlipbook?userId=1253&catalogId=4&companyId=5 is null
I/UrlLauncher( 4241): component name for http://flutter.dev is null
D/EGL_emulation( 4241): app_time_stats: avg=8004.63ms min=8004.63ms max=8004.63ms count=1
[log] @@@@@:false
```

```
 _launchURL() async {
    var url =
        "http://164.52.195.127:8080/ProductCatalogManagement/mFlipbook?userId=${StorageUtil.getString(localStorageKey.USERID!)}&catalogId=4&companyId=5";
    var Url = Uri.parse(url);
    try {
      var canLaunch = await canLaunchUrl(Url); // Await here
      log('@@@@@:${canLaunch}');
      if (canLaunch) {
        log('URL : ${Url}');
        await launchUrl(
          Url,
          mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
        );
      } else {
        globalUtils.showNegativeSnackBar(
            context: context, message: 'Cannot launch URL');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      globalUtils.showNegativeSnackBar(
          context: context, message: 'Error launching URL: $e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: you should provide more information, it is really hard to understand what the problem is

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  elements to your AndroidManifest.xml file according to package.

Or

Remove canLaunch(url) to resolved the issue